# How to call ASK() on row in Acumatica

Tags: c#, acumatica

In the "Acumatica Framework
Fundamental Course" they show using the row of an event to get a Data View and call the Ask() Method.

But when I try to do this, I get an error that the Ask() method is not available.

Here is what the Framework Course shows:

```
protected virtual void ShipmentLine_RowDeleting(
 PXCache sender, PXRowDeletingEventArgs e)
{
 ShipmentLine line = e.Row as ShipmentLine;
 if (sender.GetStatus(line) != PXEntryStatus.InsertedDeleted)
 {
 // Asking for confirmation on an attempt to delete a
 // shipment line other than the gift card line
 if (ShipmentLines.Ask("Confirm Delete",
 "Are you sure?",
 MessageButtons.YesNo) != WebDialogResult.Yes)
 {
 e.Cancel = true;
 }
 }
}
```

And this is what I am doing:

```
    protected virtual void _(Events.RowSelected<SOOrder> e)
    {
        if (e.Row is null) return;
        SOOrder row = e.Row as SOOrder;
        row.Ask("Ask User something", MessageButtons.OK);
    }
```

But there is no way to call Ask().

[image: Error message]

Has this changed in 2021 R2?

How can I get the data view?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found it in the new 2021 R2 Customization Guide.

What I was looking for was:

```
                Base.Document.Ask("Customer is currently on Credit Hold", MessageButtons.OK);
```

Weirdly, in VS Studio, when this is hit it is seen as a thrown exception, so I also have to catch it to keep the customization from erroring out when it hits this.

FWIW.

Comment: Just an FYI, if I were you I would avoid doing UI stuff in Events (Unless it is in the row selected). Especially detail events. As the Ask updates the UI and then call backs to the graph with the response. What I would do in this case is create a new delete button that calls the ask for the confirmation, and hide the acumatica delete button replacing it with your own. This would be the "cleaner" solution. Also as you have might guessed the Ask method can only be called on views and not directly on DACs.

Comment: @JeanClaudeAbela - I think I understand what you are saying, but in this case, creating a delete button would not work. The idea is that if they are on credit Hold, that we do not permit them to create a new Service Order at all. So, I want to catch when they select a customer on credit hold, and disable the save buttons, while letting them know why. How would it be best to do that?